# Modular ASP.NET Web API: how to add/remove route at run time to a Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to design a modular Web API application (It is not an MVC app!) in which a user in admin role can add or remove modules without restarting the ASP.NET application.

- Module: each module is an assembly (.dll file) that contains at least one class which is derived from `ApiController`.
- Routing is based on [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
- Production of modules (assemblies) is not in the scope of this question.
- Modules (assembly files) are copied to / deleted from `~/plugins/ folder in the root of the project. This process is not in the scope of this question either.
- The main ASP.NET Web API project has basically only one controller to manage (add/remove) modules. The other controllers will be added as modules.

So the only controller in the main Web API project is:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/modules")]
public class ModulesController : ApiController
{
    private ModuleService _moduleService = new ModuleService();

    // GET: api/Modules
    [Route]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return _moduleService.Get().Select(a => a.FullName);
    }

    // POST: api/Modules/{moduleName}
    [Route("{id}")]
    public void Post(string id)
    {
        Assembly _assembly;
        var result = _moduleService.TryLoad(id, out _assembly);

        if(!result) throw new Exception("problem loading " + id);

        // Refresh routs or add the new rout
        Configuration.Routes.Clear();
        Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        // ^ it does not work :(
    }

    // DELETE: api/Modules/{moduleName}
    [Route("{id}")]
    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        _moduleService.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

`ModuleService.TryLoad()` simply finds and loads the assembly to the application domain by using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load()`. This part is working well.

`Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` doesn't raise any error, but it breaks the whole routing system. After that line, any routing attempt causes this error:

> The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.

I added `HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized()` to the code, but it didn't resolve the problem (same error).

### Questions

1. Does this design make any sense? Will it work?
2. How can I add a new route to the route collection or refresh the route collection completely?

Comment: Try to call `Configuration.Initializer(Configuration);`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you. It resolved the error. But it seems that  `Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` doesn't pick the routes from the other assembly. It just searches the route inside the main project. I am looking to see if there is any overload fir it that we can pass the assembly name or path.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915205/web-api-2-is-it-possible-to-load-a-route-controller-programmatically

Comment: That SO question still has error thrown. Where you able to add/register the controller and the associated routes successfully?

Comment: @alltej turns out that Web API uses `BuildManager` that collect all of the DLLs from `/bin` folder at the start-up time. Unlike `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`, it is not possible to add or load new DLL to `BuildManager` after the Web API has been loaded. So I guess this is a dead-end :(
If somebody wants to restart the Web API app after adding modules, it's doable, but my intention was not to restart the application.

Comment: Have you look into MEF ( Managed Extensibility Framework) to solve your problem?

Comment: @alltej yes. but I don't like it. MEF pollutes the code with too many attributes. The intention here is to develop a core application (like a host) that accept pluggable Web APIs. I had developed kinda the same thing with MVC 4 which loads all the assemblies (core + modules) at the start up (from different folders). I hoped  I could do it with a Web API application, this time in a way that adding a new assembly doesn't need restarting the whole app. 
Unfortunately, I can't see a way to do so.
I haven't looked at ASP.NET Core, hope this would be doable there.

Comment: I read this, but can't understand it quite well: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/898/inject-dynamic-runtime-controllers-libraries-aspnet-webapi

Comment: Actually, I found a way to deliver the designer functionality by replacing the `IHttpControllerSelector`. I will post the answer + codes later. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it.

Firstly, and thanks to [@Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l), a little change to the `ModuleController` (adding `Configuration.Initializer(Configuration)`):

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/modules")]
public class ModulesController : ApiController
{
    private ModuleService _moduleService = new ModuleService();

    // Other codes

    public void Post(string id)
    {
        _moduleService.Load(id);

        Configuration.Routes.Clear();
        Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        Configuration.Initializer(Configuration);
    }

    // Other codes
}
```

Then we should extend `DefaultHttpControllerSelector`:

```cs
public class ModularHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

    public ModularHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping()
    {
        var result = base.GetControllerMapping();
        AddPluginsControllerMapping(ref result);
        return result;
    }

    private void AddPluginsControllerMapping(ref IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> controllerMappings)
    {
        var custom_settings = _getControllerMapping();

        foreach (var item in custom_settings)
        {
            if (controllerMappings.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                controllerMappings[item.Key] = item.Value;
            else
                controllerMappings.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }

    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> _getControllerMapping()
    {
        var result = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var duplicateControllers = new HashSet<string>();
        Dictionary<string, ILookup<string, Type>> controllerTypeGroups = GetControllerTypeGroups();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ILookup<string, Type>> controllerTypeGroup in controllerTypeGroups)
        {
            string controllerName = controllerTypeGroup.Key;

            foreach (IGrouping<string, Type> controllerTypesGroupedByNs in controllerTypeGroup.Value)
            {
                foreach (Type controllerType in controllerTypesGroupedByNs)
                {
                    if (result.Keys.Contains(controllerName))
                    {
                        duplicateControllers.Add(controllerName);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.TryAdd(controllerName, new HttpControllerDescriptor(_configuration, controllerName, controllerType));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (string duplicateController in duplicateControllers)
        {
            HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor;
            result.TryRemove(duplicateController, out descriptor);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ILookup<string, Type>> GetControllerTypeGroups()
    {
        IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver = new DefaultAssembliesResolver(); //was: _configuration.Services.GetAssembliesResolver();
        IHttpControllerTypeResolver controllersResolver = new DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver(); //was: _configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerTypeResolver();

        ICollection<Type> controllerTypes = controllersResolver.GetControllerTypes(assembliesResolver);
        var groupedByName = controllerTypes.GroupBy(
            t => t.Name.Substring(0, t.Name.Length - DefaultHttpControllerSelector.ControllerSuffix.Length),
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        return groupedByName.ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => g.ToLookup(t => t.Namespace ?? String.Empty, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

And of course we have to replace the default HttpControllerSelector with our HttpControllerSelector, in the `App_start\WebApiConfig.cs`:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
            typeof(System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerSelector),
            new ModularHttpControllerSelector(config));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

<del>If anybody is interested in how I implemented the `ModuleService`, I can upload the code to GitHub.</del>

Here is the whole source code in the GitHub: https://github.com/tohidazizi/modular-web-api-poc

Comment: I would be interested how you implemented it. The one I am working is it gets loaded during start-up. Yours is pretty much dynamic which will be something nice to have as well. Thanks!

Comment: @alltej - I updated the above answer with a link to the source code on GitHub. Just remember that this code is a proof of concept, not the best implementation. It needs to be fully implemented for a better performance. For example, I haven't implement any cache.

Comment: @Tohid: Can you tell me how I can unload the assembly when user call DELETE method?

Comment: Hi @anhtuangv . Here is a good blog post by Shazwazza about how it works:
https://shazwazza.com/post/developing-a-plugin-framework-in-aspnet-with-medium-trust/
It is a little complicated buy it works.
The trust level of your app on the server is also important.

Comment: @anhtuangv - ...and in case you are interested in .NET Core : 
https://shazwazza.com/post/custom-assembly-loading-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: @Tohid: Thank you very much.